# Para o que serve uma entrada TXT (TXT record) em um domínio?

Tags: dns, domínio

Geralmente, usa-se a entrada `TXT` (TXT record) quando vai configurar um domínio para apontar para um servidor de e-mails.

Eu gostaria de saber qual é o objetivo do `TXT`.

- Para que serve uma entrada `TXT`?
- Como se lê a configuração `TXT` de um determinado domínio?
- A quem interessa que eu tenha um `TXT` configurado no meu domínio?
- Quais são as vantagens de se saber isso no dia-a-dia de programação?
- Quantos registros `TXT` posso ter por domínio?

Comment: TXT é entrada livre, serve pra qualquer coisa que quiser implementar. Um uso comum (que deu origem à pergunta, no chat da rede) é o SPF, mas isso é só um de muitos usos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou tentar ser mais objetivo possível nas respostas:

**Para que serve uma entrada TXT?**
Um registro TXT (registro de texto) é um tipo de registro de recurso no DNS, que contém informações de texto de fontes fora do seu domínio, usado para associar texto arbitrário a um host, como informações legíveis sobre um servidor, rede, etc.Você pode usar os registros TXT para impedir phishing e spamming.

**Como se lê a configuração TXT de um determinado domínio?**
Como disse o José Maia, para ler a configuração, é feito da mesma forma que qualquer outro lookup de DNS, i.e. NSLookup.exe -q=TXT example.com ou dig -t txt example.com.

**A quem interessa que eu tenha um TXT configurado no meu domínio?**
O host de domínio mantém os registros DNS, que direcionam o tráfego da Internet para seu nome de domínio. Quando você adiciona um registro de verificação TXT registros DNS do seu host de domínio. caso aja alguma verificação (por exemplo por parte do Google para usar serviços como o G Suite), a propriedade do seu domínio é confirmada.

**Quais são as vantagens de se saber isso no dia-a-dia de programação?**
O foco principal é ter uma visão geral de que você ter um registro TXT confirma que você é o proprietário do seu domínio, por exemplo quando o Google ou Office365, etc, vê o registro, a propriedade do domínio é confirmada.

**Quantos registros TXT posso ter por domínio?**
Um domínio pode ter vários registros TXT associados a ele, desde que a implementação do servidor DNS ofereça suporte a isso. Porém você não pode ter mais de um registro TXT para o SPF (Sender Policy Framework) de um domínio. Se o domínio tiver mais de um registro SPF, você receberá erros de email, bem como os problemas de classificação de spam e de entrega.

***Obs: O registro de verificação não afeta seu website ou e-mail.***

Answer (score 2):

O objetivo da entrada TXT é colocar texto arbitrário. Isto leva a que diferentes sites utilizem isto para objetivos diferentes, não havendo propriamente um caso de uso 'genérico'.

Um exemplo é a Google: para utilizarmos a suite empresarial (G Suite) deles [(ver aqui detalhes)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=en&ref_topic=2716886), é pedido ao utilizador que coloque uma informação na sua configuração de DNS, para que a Google confirme que efetivamente esse utilizador é dono do DNS em questão. Outro exemplo é o uso do SPF mencionado acima no contexto do servidor de email.

Segundo o [RFC que define os registos TXT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1464), não há qualquer limite de tamanho ou de números de registo TXT explícito, sendo que pode haver implementações de servidores DNS que imponham esse limite ou até que não suportem os registos TXT.

Para ler a configuração, é feito da mesma forma que qualquer outro lookup de DNS, i.e. `NSLookup.exe -q=TXT example.com` ou `dig -t txt example.com`.